# Split a file with conflict markers

Tags: diff, merge-conflict-resolution

I am looking for a tool that will split a file that has conflict markers into the two separate files.  Is there anything out there that does this already?

Comment: I ended up writing a Perl script to do this.  https://github.com/quincy/Unmerge-Conflicts

I'd still be interested to know about existing tools that do this though.

Comment: You should list your perl script as an answer...

Comment: I accepted the xxdiff answer by @MartinMonperrus since it is more complete than my Perl script ever was.

Comment: @QuincyBowers: Don't sell yourself short; I needed to use your perl script since I had to do some bulk handling post-extract (line ending conversions on one of the halves.) Useful and worth an answer.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it was of use @jtniehof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xxdiff can do that:

```
xxdiff --unmerge myfile.txt
```

it also works if the conflict markers result from a 3-way diff

```
xxdiff --unmerge3 myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The tool I work for ([ECMerge](http://www.elliecomputing.com)) does that, primarily with the target of helping you to merge them visually of course. You could as well save the left/right/ancestor files with the built-in Javascript engine. ECMerge reads markers for most 'well-known' source code controls (CVS, git, mercurial, bazaar, SubVersion, Perforce, those compatible with the previously cited and of course its own markers!).

Answer (score 1):

Winmerge does that, they call it "Resolve conflict files". It only works on Windows though.

Answer (score 1):

As requested, my own solution to my question was to create the following Perl script.

http://github.com/quincy/Unmerge-Conflicts