# automatically resolve conflicts in checked-in file using command line

Tags: git, diff, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a freshly cloned project (git) that has a file checked in with not properly resolved conflicts (xml, part of a unit test).

It contains thousands of lines like the below (git doesn't complain about any merge conflicts whatsoever, since it is checked in like that).

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
            <id>8e1c7ee3-613c-419a-bf15-51e00d5fff5e</id>
            <idStr>8e1c7ee3-613c-419a-bf15-51e00d5fff5e</idStr>
=======
            <id>663ad7cc-2f47-48db-af8f-0d6efd4c8bd9</id>
            <idStr>663ad7cc-2f47-48db-af8f-0d6efd4c8bd9</idStr>
>>>>>>> project/master
```

Is there a linux command to create the two original files from this, so that I can chose the appropriate one?

Comment: This is a similar question, it does not have an accepted answer, but you may find something that can be of any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894114/split-a-file-with-conflict-markers